# find WithinHorizon method returns null

Tags: java, regex, file, methods, null

My findWithinHorizon method is returning null when searching through a file for the string "$DATA ASCII". The same method can find other strings such as "Array Start".

This is my code for searching the file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchingFilesMain {

public static void main(String[] arg) {

    String checker;
    String pattern1= "$DATA ASCII";

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\asciiTracks.txt")));
        checker = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern1,0);
        System.out.println(checker);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }}}
```

This is part of the file as seen in notepad++ :

```
$DATA ASCII

$DATA_INFO
Array Start                     = 0 * 126
$PROCESSING_INFO
Generation Time                 = 13:53:42
$GENERAL
Tx Time                         = 450.079
Tx Time Abs                     = 1080309222.55633
Tx Clock                        = 13:53:42
Cerb Tracker Whole Time         = 0.015
Num contacts                    = 699
$DATA ASCII

$DATA_INFO
Array Start                     = 0 * 127
$PROCESSING_INFO
Generation Time                 = 13:53:45
$GENERAL
Tx Time                         = 453.219
Tx Time Abs                     = 1080309225.69626
Tx Clock                        = 13:53:45
Cerb Tracker Clutter processing = 0.016
Cerb Tracker Whole Time         = 0.016
Num contacts                    = 666
$DATA ASCII
```

I have no idea why then method cannot search through this code to find "$DATA ASCII", can anyone think of any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a meta-character in regular expressions used to denote the end of a `String`. It needs to be escaped

```
String pattern1 = "\\$DATA ASCII";
```